# Mailing Address Concern while renewing California Driver's Licence?

Tags: driving-license, california

I am in Los Angeles and moving to Bay Area but before that I am going to renew my Driver's license.

I am sure that DMV will be providing me a temporary license (paper one) and they are going to mail the permanent one on my mailing address. Since, during this time I will be moving to Bay Area,
is it possible to fill my Bay Area address and ask DMV people to mail it over there?
Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course it is, but keep in mind that it may arrive there before you so you need to make sure someone you know picks up the mail. From my experience it takes about 2-3 weeks.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I will be leaving for Bay Area right after getting my paper license so I will be able to easily pick it up.

Comment: Could you explain me where I will get an option of filling a different mailing address at DMV?

Comment: @John there's only one address on your driver license, and that is where they'll send it to.

Comment: @littleadv Are you sure about that?  The DL44 application form has space for both a mailing address and a residence address. I would assume they print the second one on the license card, and mail it to the  first one. See https://www.dmv.ca.gov/portal/dmv/forms/teenweb/permit_btn1/dl44sample.pdf (pdf) for an example.